# ReactJS : insert svg Emoji into Rect of SVG

Tags: html, user-interface, svg, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and working on SVG, 
The following ReactJS code snippet creates 9 tiles filled with different colors.

```
import React from 'react';
class SvgRectDashboard extends React.Component {
  render(){
    var svgText = (<svg height="170px" width="364px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <g transform="translate(0,0)">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC99" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect11"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC66" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect12"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC33" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect13"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC00" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect21"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect22"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect23"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9700" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect31"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9933" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect32"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF6600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect33"></rect>
       </g>
      </svg>);
    return (<div>{svgText}</div>);
  }
}
module.exports = SvgRectDashboard;
```

the Emojis are in img/svg/1f3c8.svg

My requirement is need to insert Emojis in some of tiles( Rect tiles) as shown image.
 
 I have tried the following ways. but i could not make it.

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="background:'url(img/svg/1f600.svg)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect11"></rect>

<rect x="0" y="55" width="118" height="55" style={background:'url(img/svg/1f600.svg)} stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect11"></rect>
```

Can you please help me out. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to fill the rect elements with a pattern and configure the pattern so it holds the image you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to add your emoji elements to the end of the SVG file.  Position them as appropriate.

You haven't provided an example of one of your emojis, so I am using a green circle as a stand-in.

```html
<svg height="170px" width="364px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <g transform="translate(0,0)">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="black" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect11"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC66" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect12"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC33" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect13"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC00" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect21"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect22"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect23"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9700" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect31"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9933" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect32"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF6600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect33"></rect>
       </g>
  
       <circle id="pretend-emoji" cx="59" cy="27" r="20" fill="green"/>
 </svg>
```

If your emoji SVG contains just a single emoji, then you could just do something like:

```
<svg height="170px" width="364px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <g transform="translate(0,0)">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="black" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect11"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC66" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect12"></rect>
          <rect x="0" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC33" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect13"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FFCC00" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect21"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect22"></rect>
          <rect x="118" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect23"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="0" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9700" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect31"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="55" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF9933" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect32"></rect>
          <rect x="236" y="110" width="118" height="55" fill="#FF6600" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect33"></rect>
       </g>

       <svg x="0" y="0" xlink:href="img/svg/1f600.svg"/>
 </svg>
```

Where the X and Y attributes of the child SVG (the one for the emoji) correspond to the X and Y of the rectangle it is supposed to be over.  With perhaps an offset if your emoji SVG is not the same size as the rectangles.